# SPX3819 LDO output drops very low under small loads

Tags: ldo

I am troubleshooting a LDO that drops the output way down from 5V when put under very small loads. With a 100 Ohm load, it will typically drop below 4V, for example. Varies from board to board. In one extreme case, i've seen it drop all the way down to the minimum of 1.235V, almost as if R1 and R2 don't exist at all. This does not seem to remain consistent with the 0.4% load regulation in the datasheet.

VOUT = 1.235V x [1 + R1/R2] = 1.235V x [1 + 100/33] ~ 5V

From the datasheet of this LDO, it should be able to source 500mA. Dropout voltage also appears to be within the correct range. VIN is very stable. One hypothesis is that R1 and R2 are overheating but they don't seem to be getting very hot (100F).

Based on the schematic alone, is this LDO being used correctly?

SPX3819S-L/TR
https://assets.maxlinear.com/web/documents/spx3819.pdf

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPFCBJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What type of capacitor are you using for C1? The datasheet talks about alli and tant, but not ceramic. Are you using a ceramic? Some regulators, especially LDOs, require higher ESR from their load caps than ceramic have, for stability. Lack of stability often presents as poor regulation.

Comment: Using ceramics for both C1 and C2. Was wondering about that as well.

Comment: LDOs that work ceramic caps usually brag about it in the datasheet then add a lecture about how many µF remain in the cap once it's biased. If the datasheet only says "aluminium" or "tantalum" it requires the ESR to be stable. Probe it with a scope, it's probably oscillating. You can try a few ohms resistor in series with C1.

Comment: What does the input voltage drop to when the output drops under load?

Comment: @Andyaka Steady 8V at the input. We just found that if you increase the load current (make R_Load smaller), the output stabilizes. Seems to imply that there's some minimum load spec but I don't see such a spec in the datasheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just want to update on what i've attempted. Might be one possible solution.

2.2uF aluminum capacitor: Same result. Significant output voltage drops down to the minimum 1.225 when under even very small loads.

2.2uF low ESR ceramic: voltage drops immediately with no load at all.

2.2uF low ESR ceramic + 5 Ohms series resistance: This seems to work best. Output remains constant with minimal drop throughout the full 0 - 500mA range. Noise is not great but less than 100mV p-p. Maybe the most important thing here is that the series resistance remains constant?

Correction: Noise is bad.. 500mV p-p. That could just be my circuit.

Another update today:
Turns out the input to my LDO was extremely noisy. Once I stabilized the input, the output became stable. It's also answered in a FAQ from the manufacturer that ceramic caps can be used with this LDO so it had nothing to do with that.

Comment: 100mV noise sounds like it may still be oscillating. You could post your board images, but maybe time to select a less finicky regulator.

Comment: @user1850479 That was a miscalculation. it's worse than that... 500mV. Is this LDO some old tech? Is there something better that isn't so picky about the output cap?

Comment: It is fairly old since it mentions tantalum capacitors.  For LDOs it is much easier if you pick parts that specify ceramic capacitors.   If you want to fix the current design, try increasing the input and output capacitance and then try a few values of the series resistor.